# Cosine factor in directional hemispherical reflectance

Tags: rendering, raytracing

Directional hemispherical reflectance is the ratio between exitance to incoming irradiance. It is used to estimate degree of energy conservation

```
R(l) = exitance / irradiance
```

I can understand the relation between BRDF and R(l). BRDF is target to specific viewing angle. so the numerator is radiance. R(l) can be obtain by integrating brdf over all viewing direction.

```
R(l) = integral(brdf(l, v) * cos(theta0) * dw0)
```

theta0 is angle between n and v

My question is where do the cosine factor come from?

Answer (score 0):

The angle `theta0` should be the angle between incident light and surface normal. The closer incident light flux comes to surface normal, the greater energy surface receives (this is the case for `cos(theta0) = 1`).

The formula itself comes from the derivation of BRDF.

Comment: as you said "the greater energy surface receives".  however, R(l) is (energy surface emit) / (energy surface receives). I think this statement could not imply R(l) get bigger.

Comment: Ok, if you insert exact BRDF expression like `brdf(l,v) = dL(l) / (L(v) * cos(theta0) * dw0)` inside integral, the same terms `cos(theta0)` and `dw0` in numerator and denominator will go away, and you will get only the ratio like `dL(l)/L(v)`. The last one is integrated over the hemisphere.

Answer (score 0):

The directional hemispherical reflectance is the albedo of a surface which is being illuminated by a single, directional light source. This means that there is only a single direction for which there is illumination reaching the surface.

Since the lighting term is a delta function, the dimensionality of the integral is reduced and we only have to integrate over the viewing directions. The cosine term projects the differential solid angle of the light onto the surface

So it's basically a stripped down version of the rendering equation using the simplified light source.